# Can't mount Samba share inside router connected to OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, samba, android

Inside my router (connected to an OpenVPN server) is a Samba share.
I try to mount that share with my mobile phone (connected to the same OpenVPN server), but this does not work.

### My (reducted) OpenVPN server.conf:

```
local my_ip_address
port port_number
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /path/to/ca.crt
cert /path/to/cert.crt
key /path/to/private.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /path/to//dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway ipv6 def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS mydns_1"
push "dhcp-option DNS mydns_2"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /path/to//ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher top_secret
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /path/to/openvpn-status.log
log         /path/to/openvpn.log
log-append  /path/to/openvpn.log

verb 4

auth-user-pass-optional
plugin /path/to/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login


client-config-dir ccd

route 192.168.70.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.70.0 255.255.255.0"

server-ipv6 my_ipv6 
push tun-ipv6
push "route-ipv6 my_ipv6"
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"


push "dhcp-option DNS myipv6dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS myipv6dns"
```

```
##  My reducted smb.conf:

[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = home.mustafejen.se
interfaces = driver_name
domain master = yes 
domain logons = yes
wins support = yes
dns proxy = yes
hostname lookups = yes
name resolve order = wins lmhosts host bcast
smb ports = 445 139 138 137
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = file
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

printing = cups
printcap = cups

[printers]
 
comment = All Printers
browseable = yes
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]

comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes

[samba-share]
comment = Samba on Debian
#valid users = user1, user2, user3
path = /home/me/Musik
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
hosts.allow = 192.168.70.0/24 10.8.0.0/24 127.0.0.1
browsable = yes

[mappen]
comment = Samba on Debian
valid users = per
path = /home/me
writable = yes
guest ok = no
#hosts.allow = 
browsable = yes
```

```
## Attempt to show routing table on OpenVPN server

netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
185.12.64.1     172.31.1.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
185.12.64.2     172.31.1.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
192.168.70.0    10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
```

(192.168.70.0 is inside my router, where my Samba share is)

My router and mobile phone both have addresses from 10.8.0.0 subnet.
The OpenVPN server successfully redirects traffis from my PC (inside the router)
and mobile phone (outside the router).

My smb.log does not output anything when I try to mount the share,
I don't even get an error message.

The Android Cx File Explorer gives me a timeout error.

Edit: I noticed one thing:
I can ping 10.8.0.1 but not the routing tables gateway 10.8.0.2

Comment: Remember that routes have to be bi-directional. Furthermore, if you want any help you'll have to explain what's what, and preferably include a topology. Furthermore, note that home system questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: I figured it out. I had errounously named the file in the ccd directory to the same name as the arbitrary name I typed into the "Description" input form in the OpenVPN Client Settings admin web page of my router.

Comment: The right thing to do in my case was naming the file in the ccd directory after the client's X509 common name, which I figured out after consulting the manual page of openvpn.